# Add style to array element from another object array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array, that represents the question numbers.

There is an another object array, that contains user answer (question number and whether user's answer is correct or wrong).

```
questions = [] // question numbers
validity = [{answer: true, questionNo: "2"},{answer: false, questionNo: "3"}] // user answers array
```

What i'm trying to do is, highlight correct questions with green color and wrong questions with red color.

I tried below when `validity` array has two records, however, it only highlited last record:

```
{
  questions.map((i, index) => {
    let className = '';
    if (validity) {
      validity.map((data) => {
        if (Object.keys(data).length) {
          if ((Number(data.questionNo) === index)) {
            if (data.answer) {
              className = `question-list correct-q` // when answer `true`,set div to green color
            } else {
              className = `question-list wrong-q` // when answer `false`,set div to red
            }
          } else {
            className = `question-list` // default div color
          }
        }
      })
    
    } else {
      className = `question-list`
    }
    return (index != 0) && 
      <div 
        className={className} 
        key={index} 
        onClick={() => onclickQuestion(index)}
      >
        Q - {index}
      </div>
  })
}
```

[image]

I want to color `Q-2` with green color and `Q-3` with red color at same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first turn your validity array into an object where the key is the question number and the value is the validity and then use that instead using [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```
const validityObject = validity.reduce((obj, question) => {
  obj[parseInt(question.questionNo)] = question.answer;

  return obj;
}, {});
```

`validityObject`:

```
{
  "2": true,
  "3": false
}
```

Now, you can simplify the logic inside the loop and use that instead of a nested loop, which is simpler and more performant (as you only need to do an object lookup to check the validity of each question):

```js
const questions = Array.from(Array(20), (_, i) => i + 1);

const validity =[{
  answer: true,
  questionNo: "2"
 },{
  answer: false,
  questionNo: "3"
}];

const validityObject = validity.reduce((obj, question) => {
  obj[parseInt(question.questionNo)] = question.answer;
  
  return obj;
}, {});

document.getElementById('root').innerHTML = questions.map((questionNumber) => {
  const valid = validityObject[questionNumber];

  let className = 'question-list';   

  if (valid === true) {
    className = 'question-list correct-q';
  } else if (valid === false) {
    className = 'question-list wrong-q';
  }
         
  return `
    <div class="${ className }">
     Q - ${ questionNumber }
    </div>
  `;
}).join('');
```

```css
.question-list {
  border: 2px solid #F0F0F0;
  padding: 8px;
  font-family: monospace;
  margin: 8px 0 0 0;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.correct-q {
  border-color: green;
}

.wrong-q {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Great.This one is nice and simple.Thank you @Danziger

Answer (score 2):

You can find validity object using `Array.find()` like this:

```js
{
  questions.map((i, index) => {
    let className = 'question-list'; // default
    const answerObj = validity.find(answer => answer.questionNo == index);
    const isValid = answerObj.answer;
    if (isValid) {
      className = 'question-list correct-q' // when answer "true", set div to green color
    } else {
      className = 'question-list wrong-q' // when answer "false", set div to red
    }
  })
  // ...
}
```